# Can I prevent IDA from closing the view when I hit the Escape key?

Tags: ida

In the IDA View, I frequently use the Escape key to move the cursor back to the previous location.  However, sometimes I accidentally hit the Escape key while the focus is still on another view, which causes that view to close.  Reopening and positioning the affected view every time this happens can be cumbersome.  **Is there a way to disable the Escape key *only* for particular views?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this is possible.

Navigate to the IDA program directory and open `cfg\idagui.cfg`.  If you scroll down, you should see something like this:

```
// Built-in window ids
#define BWN_EXPORTS 0x00000001 // exports
#define BWN_IMPORTS 0x00000002 // imports
#define BWN_NAMES   0x00000004 // names
... several lines removed ...
#define BWN_DISASMS 0x20000000 // disassembly views
#define BWN_DUMPS   0x40000000 // hex dumps
#define BWN_NOTEPAD 0x80000000 // notepad

CLOSED_BY_ESC           = 0x9A0FFFFF    // All windows that are closed by Esc.
                                        // If a windows is not closed by Esc,
                                        // it can be closed by Alt-F3.
                                        // (disasm/hexdump/navband can not be closed by Esc)
```

Unset bits from the `CLOSED_BY_ESC` variable that correspond to the views that you do not want to close with the Escape key.  Then save and reopen IDA.